# Does adding a list unassigned to a variable to another variable pointing to a different list create a new list object?

Tags: python, list, memory, mutable

Here's what I mean:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
y = y + [4]
```

It's to my understanding that the variable `y` points to the variable `x`, which stores  the list object [1, 2, 3]. At the second line of code, both `x` and `y` store the same id. In the last line of code, we are changing what the variable `y` stores. Will adding the list `[4]` to y create a new list object containing an int object for 4? I'm pretty sure both `x` and `y` still point to the same id since lists are mutable, I just need confirmation on the [4]. Is a new list and int object created?

Comment: Lists are not immutable. `tuple`s are. But that has no bearing on the behavior of the particular code you list here.

Comment: Have you used an assignment operator? And what does `y is x` say?

Comment: Oops, yep! My bad!

Comment: Yes,does that mean a new int object is created to store the number 4? And it would say True, so both x and y would be pointing to the list [1, 2, 3, 4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it! I had it wrong, a new object is created for `y` in the third line! it's the list [1, 2, 3, 4]. The variable x still refers to the `list` [1, 2, 3]. Adding [4] is similar to the .extend() function in python in which a new int object would be created for 4, but not a new list object to contain that int!

Answer (score 0):

The expression `y + [4]` creates a new list that is the result of adding `[4]` to whatever `y` contains. Assigning the result of that expression to `y` changes `y` to point to the new list that was created.

This is not really any different than the following code:

```
y = 1
y = y + 1
```

After this code, `y` will be `2`, and the meaning of `1` has not changed.

Comment: Checking this on Idle though, I get that the id of y in the first line is the same as the id of y after adding [4]. So in a sense, aren't we just appending 4 to the list y rather than creating a new list?